# Resetting counter

Tags: counters

I have created two counters

```
\newcounter{problem}[section]
\newcounter{solution}[problem]
```

As expected, **problem** resets every time **section** increases.

However, **solution** does not reset when **problem** increases.

What is the problem?

Comment: Please provide a minimal example.

Comment: just a guess but are you using `\advance` rather than `\stepcounter` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use `\stepcounter` or `\refstepcounter` to trigger the reset code. If you set the value in other ways then you need to reset the other counter to `0` explicitly.

If you get `\endcsname` errors that is another problem and probably needs another question. But if you ask a question please give people half a chance of answering it by providing a *complete* (small) document that produces the error.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you want to present multiple solutions to a problem? Then you could do it like this:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcounter{problem}[section]
\newcounter{solution}[problem]
\renewcommand{\thesolution}{\arabic{problem}.\arabic{solution}}


\begin{document}

\section{one}
\stepcounter{problem}problem \theproblem\\
\stepcounter{solution}solution \thesolution\\
\stepcounter{solution}solution \thesolution\\
\stepcounter{solution}solution \thesolution\\

\stepcounter{problem}problem \theproblem\\
\stepcounter{solution}solution \thesolution\\
\stepcounter{solution}solution \thesolution\\

\section{one}
\stepcounter{problem}problem \theproblem\\
\stepcounter{solution}solution \thesolution\\
\stepcounter{solution}solution \thesolution\\
\stepcounter{solution}solution \thesolution\\
\stepcounter{solution}solution \thesolution\\

\stepcounter{problem}problem \theproblem\\
\stepcounter{solution}solution \thesolution\\
\stepcounter{solution}solution \thesolution\\
\stepcounter{solution}solution \thesolution\\

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In such a case it would probably be better to treat problems and solutions as theorem like enviornments.  Using `amsthm` and `amsmath` you can set-up this up with e.g. `\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{solution}{Solution}
\numberwithin{solution}{problem}` in the preamble to get the type of numbering you desire.