# Reset custom counter in new frame

Tags: beamer, counters, overlays

I'm using a custom counter to cycle bullet point colours in beamer:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{marvosym}

\newcommand{\myitem}[1]{\item[{\textcolor{#1}\Laserbeam}]}
\newcounter{myc}%[frame] <--if I uncomment [frame] it won't compile
\makeatletter
\def\newitem{
\stepcounter{myc}%
\ifnum\value{myc}=1
  \myitem{red}
\else\ifnum\value{myc}=2
  \myitem{green}
\else\ifnum\value{myc}=3
  \myitem{blue}
  \setcounter{myc}{0}
\fi\fi\fi
}
 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \newitem An item
        \newitem Another item
        \newitem Yet another item
        \newitem These items...
        \newitem ...are rather boring
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \newitem An item on a second slide
        \newitem Another item
        \newitem Yet another item
        \newitem These items...
        \newitem ...are rather boring
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

with the following result (2 slides combined in to 1 image)
[image: example, non resetting]

However I would like the colours to reset at the start of a new frame, without having to insert `\setcounter{myc}{0}` after each `\begin{frame}`  Based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66604/resetting-counter) I thought I might be able to use `\newcounter{myc}[frame]`, but I can't: `! LaTeX Error: No counter 'frame' defined.`

So how do I reset a counter per frame?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were near: the counter is called `framenumber`. There's an easier way to branch for numeric cases.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{marvosym}

\newcommand{\myitem}[1]{\item[{\textcolor{#1}\Laserbeam}]}
\newcounter{myc}[framenumber]
\newcommand\newitem{%
  \stepcounter{myc}%
  \ifcase\value{myc}%
    % no value for 0
  \or
    \myitem{red}%
  \or
    \myitem{green}%
  \or
    \myitem{blue}%
    \setcounter{myc}{0}%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \newitem An item
        \newitem Another item
        \newitem Yet another item
        \newitem These items...
        \newitem ...are rather boring
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \newitem An item on a second slide
        \newitem Another item
        \newitem Yet another item
        \newitem These items...
        \newitem ...are rather boring
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

An easier way for extending the number of colors is using `xparse`; you just call `\assigncolors{red,green,blue}` or with any other list. You can issue this command any times you want during the document, but it's better to do it outside frames, to avoid multiple evaluations.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcounter{myc}[framenumber]

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\newitem}{}
 {
  \chris_newitem:
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\assigncolors}{m}
 {
  \chris_assign_colors:n { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \g_chris_colors_seq
\int_new:N \l_chris_color_int
\cs_new_protected:Npn \chris_assign_colors:n #1
 {
  \seq_gset_from_clist:Nn \g_chris_colors_seq { #1 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \chris_newitem:
 {
  \stepcounter{myc}
  \int_set:Nn \l_chris_color_int
   {
    \int_mod:nn { \value{myc} } { \seq_count:N \g_chris_colors_seq }
   }
  \int_compare:nT {\l_chris_color_int = 0 }
   {
    \int_set:Nn \l_chris_color_int { \seq_count:N \g_chris_colors_seq }
   }
  \chris_do_item:n
   {
    \seq_item:Nn \g_chris_colors_seq { \l_chris_color_int }
   }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \chris_do_item:n #1
 {
  \item[ \textcolor { #1 }{ \Laserbeam } ]
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\assigncolors{red,green,blue}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \newitem An item
        \newitem Another item
        \newitem Yet another item
        \newitem These items...
        \newitem ...are rather boring
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \newitem An item on a second slide
        \newitem Another item
        \newitem Yet another item
        \newitem These items...
        \newitem ...are rather boring
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You answered my next question as well, before I even asked - that's a much easier way of increasing the number of colours

Answer (score 4):

The simplest thing to do in cases like this is to use [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) which provides the useful `\AtBeginEnvironment` macro.

So, to reset the custom counter in each frame is quite straightforward:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginEnvironment{frame}{\setcounter{myc}{0}}
```

The complete example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}% not really needed
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{marvosym}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginEnvironment{frame}{\setcounter{myc}{0}}

\newcommand{\myitem}[1]{\item[{\textcolor{#1}\Laserbeam}]}
\newcounter{myc}%[frame] <--if I uncomment [frame] it won't compile
\makeatletter
\def\newitem{
\stepcounter{myc}%
\ifnum\value{myc}=1
  \myitem{red}
\else\ifnum\value{myc}=2
  \myitem{green}
\else\ifnum\value{myc}=3
  \myitem{blue}
  \setcounter{myc}{0}
\fi\fi\fi
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \newitem An item
        \newitem Another item
        \newitem Yet another item
        \newitem These items...
        \newitem ...are rather boring
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \newitem An item on a second slide
        \newitem Another item
        \newitem Yet another item
        \newitem These items...
        \newitem ...are rather boring
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Two good answers, I've gone with egreg's, but +1 for teaching me about `\AtBeginEnvironment`

Comment: @ChrisH: you're welcome :)