# Longtable doesn't include right border

Tags: longtable

I'm trying to include a `longtable` in my work.

I'm getting all the borders I want except on the "main body" of the table the right border is missing.
(Header is appearing on every page, so that is working well)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{ltablex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % never indent first line

\begin{document}

{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{longtable}{| c | m{5cm} | m{9.5cm} | }
\hline
&  \textbf{\scshape{What you observed}} &   \textbf{\scshape{Suggestions/reasons/examples}} \\
\hline
\hline
\endhead

\hline
A & \multicolumn{2}{l | }{\textbf{SC} }\\
\hline
& \textbf{1.    P} \newline
\null \hspace{3mm} a\newline
\null \hspace{3mm} b\newline
\null \hspace{3mm}c\newline
\null \hspace{3mm}d\\
\hline
&\textbf{2. -}\newline
\null \hspace{3mm}a\newline
\null \hspace{3mm}b\newline
\null \hspace{3mm}c\newline
\null \hspace{3mm}d\newline
\null \hspace{3mm}e\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How do I need to change my code?

Comment: Add an empty cell with `&`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to suggest a couple of things.

If you want to number any element, in your case rows, use counters so you don't have to remember the next value.

LaTeX already have lists, which you can use and format via [standard methods](http://latexref.xyz/list.html) or the extra package [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem), which I did in the code below.

One disadvantage of using lists in tables is they leave extra empty line in cells. The remedy is to wrap the code for a list within `\parbox` or `minipage`. Then, whatever spacing is required has to be added manually. This is why there are two `\vsppace{...}` before and after the list.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{array}       % Adds m{...} type column
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}    % More options for lists
\usepackage{newtx}       % Change font for the example to have combine \scshape and \bfseries

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % never indent first line

\newcounter{mainlist}\renewcommand\themainlist{\arabic{mainlist}.}
\newlist{innerenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[innerenum]{
  nosep,
  label=\alph*,
}


\begin{document}
{%
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \begin{longtable}{| c| m{5cm}| m{8.5cm}|}
    \hline
    & \textbf{\textsc{What you observed}} & \textsc{\textbf{Suggestions/reasons/examples}} \\
    \hline\hline\endhead
    A & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\textbf{SC}} \\
    \hline
    & \textbf{\stepcounter{mainlist}\themainlist{} P}\par
      \parbox{\linewidth}{%
      \vspace{0.5\baselineskip}%
      \begin{innerenum}
      \item
      \item
      \item
      \item
      \end{innerenum}\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}}
    & \\
    \hline
    & \textbf{\stepcounter{mainlist}\themainlist{} -}\par
      \parbox{\linewidth}{%
      \vspace{0.5\baselineskip}%
      \begin{innerenum}
      \item
      \item
      \item
      \item
      \end{innerenum}\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}}
    & \\
    \hline
  \end{longtable}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do I reset the arabic counter once done with Part A and enumeration and want to start part B with 1. again?

Comment: For resetting a counter, use `\setcounter`, e.g. `\setcounter{mainlist}{1}` instead of `\stepcounter`. Here's [more info](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Counters).

Comment: I didn't find the link helpful, but this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66604/resetting-counter instead. This does the trick: `\newcounter{sectionR}
\setcounter{sectionR}{1}
\renewcommand\thesectionR{\Alph{sectionR}}
\newcounter{mainlist}[sectionR]
\renewcommand\themainlist{\arabic{mainlist}.}`

Answer (score 3):

- Instead of `longtable` I would rather use `longtblr` of `tabularray` package.
- For lists in the second column seems to be better to use `enumerate` list with `resume*=<list name>` option.
- In MWE below I anticipate, that table has table caption

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}   % for scshape bfseries font
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}                       

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtblr}{%
    \setlist[enumerate,1]{nosep, 
                          leftmargin = *,
                          label      = \textbf{\arabic*.},
                          after =\end{minipage},                  
                          before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}%\RagggedRight 
                         }
    \setlist[enumerate,2]{nosep,
                          leftmargin=*,
                          label = \alph*
                         }
                           }% end of AtBeginEnvironment
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % never indent first line

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Long table},
  label = {tab:longtblr}
                    ]{hlines, vlines,
                     colspec = {c X[j] X[2, j]},
                     row{1}  = {font=\bfseries\scshape},
                     measure = vbox,
                     rowhead = 1
                     }
    &  What you observed
            &   Suggestions/reasons/examples
                                        \\
\hline
A   & \SetCell[c=2]{l}  \textbf{SC}     \\
    &   \begin{enumerate}[series=tab]
    \item   \textbf{P}
            \begin{enumerate} 
        \item
        \item
        \item
        \item
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{enumerate}
        &                           \\
    &   \begin{enumerate}[resume*=tab]
    \item   \textbf{--}
            \begin{enumerate}
        \item
        \item
        \item
        \item
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{enumerate}
        &                           \\
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- In the case, if you not like to have a captions in `longtblr`, than MWE had to be:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% rest of preamble

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead, middlehead,lasthead}{default}{} % <---
\DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{normal}{\scriptsize\textit{Continued on the next page}}
\SetTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{normal}
    \begin{longtblr}[
                    ]{hlines, vlines,
                     colspec = {c X[j] X[2, j]},
                     row{1}  = {font=\bfseries\scshape},
                     measure = vbox,
                     rowhead = 1
                     }
% rest of table
\end{longtblr}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]